# Javascript/jQuery draw table with cells with specific colors to calculate an equation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a library or at least some info about pure JavaScript/jQuery scripts that helps me to create the forms in the following image, to make a nurse put an X inside the corespondent cell to calculate a medical equation called CVD ?

Here is the image:

[image]

**SOME EXPLANATION**

In my database I can know the age of each patient, the according to it, I will display the table and of course according to gender (male or female). And then we will specify his total cholesterol, and when we add the X, we see at which color the X came and we can know what is the CVD risk factor.

Of course the Y axe is for something called SOP.

The hardest part I think is how to display the background color.

Comment: Does the background need to be a colour?  Could you just use a background image?

Comment: I think the background is calculated according to the XY values and each point represents a color which define the value

Answer (score 1):

This does not address your root question, but for displaying the background color for the tables, you can use CSS gradients, adjusting the stops accordingly.

```css
.bg-grad {
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#1dae59+0,1dae59+33,f37437+34,f37437+69,e43c40+70,e43c40+70 */
  background: #1dae59; /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, #1dae59 0%, #1dae59 33%, #f37437 34%, #f37437 69%, #e43c40 70%, #e43c40 70%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, #1dae59 0%,#1dae59 33%,#f37437 34%,#f37437 69%,#e43c40 70%,#e43c40 70%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #1dae59 0%,#1dae59 33%,#f37437 34%,#f37437 69%,#e43c40 70%,#e43c40 70%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1dae59', endColorstr='#e43c40',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
table.graph {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
table.graph td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table class='graph bg-grad'>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```